biased MLEs in negative binomial models
I found the maximum likelihood parameters of negative binomial models are biased. An example code is provided below. Is this normal? Are there ways to obtain unbiased estimates?
> set.seed(3)
> z <- 2
> a <- 100
> b <- 100
> theta <- 15
> 
> negloglik <- function(p,x,y){
+ if(any(p<=0)) return(NA)
+   a <- p[1]
+   b <- p[2]
+   z <- p[3]
+   theta <- p[4]
+   -sum(dnbinom(y, mu=(a*x^z)/(b+x^z), size=theta, log=TRUE))
+ }
> 
> nsim <- 1000
> ppp <- matrix(NA,nsim,4)
> for(i in 1:nsim){
+ x <- round(rep(seq(3,30,by=5),each=5))
+ y <- rnbinom(length(x), mu=((a*x^z)/(b+x^z)), size=theta)
+ ppp[i,] <- optim(c(a,b,z,theta),negloglik,x=x,y=y)$par
+ }
> 
> # MLE (expected)
> apply(ppp,2,mean)
[1] 105.135854 123.325672   2.054681  19.150245
> 
> # bias
> apply(ppp,2,mean)-c(a,b,z,theta)
[1]  5.13585361 23.32567187  0.05468069  4.15024470


Since the sample size is quite small, we may expect some bias. As a complement to the parameters you could compare the estimated and true values for the mean $\mu$ and the index of dispersion (ID) $1 + \mu /\theta$, which both depend on $x$. I suspect that ML leads to a negative bias on the ID for small samples, as it does for the estimation of variances.

Computed in 1945 (Haldane, J. B. S. "On a method of estimating frequencies." Biometrika 33.3 (1945): 222-225.) , the MVUE is $$\hat{p} = \frac{k-1}{n-1}$$ with $k$ the number of successes and, $n=k+l$ the number of successes plus failures.

So, yes, there are unbiased estimates, but is there a more deeper question? This is not clear.

@SextusEmpiricus Yes! That's the paper that helped me explore the issue that I describe in my answer. If I recall correctly, Haldane's argument for the 'ignore the last trial' is mostly about  the utility of the better estimates that result. I have attempted to provide a principled case.

You can't really tell from this whether it's bias or just variability: you want to compare the estimated bias to the standard deviation of the estimates. In this case I think it's largely variability
(I don't get your results when I run your code, which is a bit surprising -- I get much worse results. )
In general, maximum likelihood estimates are not unbiased, but they typically do have bias that's small compared to the variability, especially in large samples.

The classically calculated maximal likelihood estimate from a negative binomial sampling experiment does indeed have bias. You can get an unbiassed estimate by omitting the last observation from the sample. That sounds like an illegal act, but there is a rationale for doing so that I worked on for a while ten years ago. I never completed that work, so this will be a rough and ready account.
It is well known that stopping rules do not affect the likelihood function, but the more detailed account is, at least according to Berger and Wolpert's widely cited book on the likelihood principle, that the stopping rules do not affect a likelihood function as long as the stopping rules are uninformative. It turns out that most stopping rules can be shown to be uninformative, and most examples of informative stopping rules sound silly. However, I would argue that the stopping rule for negative binomial sampling is informative and so it should be taken into account when constructing the likelihood function.
How is it informative? Well it is at least informative insofar as it tells you that the conventionally constructed maximum likelihood estimate will be biassed! That might suffice to say that the stopping rule needs to be taken into account when constructing the likelihood function, but it does not lead obviously to leaving out the last trial result. And I suspect that most readers will want a more technical argument.
A simple and instructive example of negative binomial sampling is where you toss a coin until the $j^{th}$ heads is observed. The conventionally calculated MLE from the result of $k$ tosses (trials) to get the $j$ heads is $j/k$, and that value is biassed. In contrast, if you decide to toss the coin $k$ times and observe $j$ heads among those $k$ tosses, then the MLE of $j/k$ is not biassed. For the negative sampling the total number of tosses is taken as the key result, whereas for the positive sampling the key result is the number of heads.
The stopping rule of negative binomial sampling the tells you the outcome of the last trial even before you start the trials. That outcome is (will be) a 'success' no matter how long the trials run before reaching the stopping condition. Normally we would think that information is not important, but if the outcome of that trial is set by the stopping rules and known with certainty even before the trials are run, why is it treated as a part of the data? It is not like the results of the other trials which might be a success or a failure.
If we condition on the both the data and the stopping rules derived fact that the $k^{th}$ result is always a success then we get to a likelihood function that ignores the last observation. And we get an unbiassed MLE.
Another way to look at the whole thing is to describe the experimental question: "How many tosses of this coin can I make before the $k^{th}$ success?" For that question it seems more reasonable to ignore the $k^{th}$ result than the more conventional question of "How many times do I need to toss this coin in order to obtain $k$ successes?". Both versions of the question support the same type of experiment, but one makes it reasonable to omit the last result and the other does not.
I'm sure that this is an area of statistical theory and philosophy that is open to more development.

I don't think the MLE will be unbiased for the parameters being estimated even with this change. The reason I don't think so is exactly that the usual parameter estimates are unbiased; the estimates here are non-linear functions of the usual ones.

@ThomasLumley "the usual parameter estimates are unbiased" My simulations and those of the original question suggest that is not correct in the case of negative sampling. As does the 1945 paper by Haldane cited by Sextus Empiricus.

Sorry, I meant the estimates of the usual parameters, not the usual estimates of the parameters.

Computed in 1945 (Haldane, J. B. S. "On a method of estimating frequencies." Biometrika 33.3 (1945): 222-225.) , the MVUE based on a single measurement is
$$\hat{p} = \frac{r−1}{r+k−1}$$
with $k$ the observed number of failures before
we have the number of required successes $r$.
The maximum likelihood estimate is
$$\tilde{p} = \frac{r}{r+k}$$
and we have the following relationships between these two estimators
$$\hat{p} = \tilde{p} \frac{r-1}{r-\tilde{p}} = h(\tilde{p}) $$
$$\tilde{p} = \hat{p} \frac{r}{r+\hat{p}-1} = h^{-1}(\hat{p}) $$

In your case the bias will be much less than the equations above suggest. This is because you have multiple measurements instead of a single measurement. That makes the bias smaller. Effectively this increases the required successes $r$ (for example, consider that the sum of multiple NB distributed variables is another NB distributed variable).
The discrepancies that you find are likely due to variance rather than bias. This variance may also be increased if the parameters have correlations (if simultaneous changes in two or more parameters don't alter the function by much, then the outcome will have a large range of error, an example is also found here: Fitting SIR model with 2019-nCoV data doesn't conververge the part about the parameters $\beta$ and $\gamma$)
